# Is there an OR operator on google place API?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am using [this api call](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests) with &keyword=  and I want to have multiple words in the keyword but OR them. I have tried OR and | but it seems to ignore it. [example here](https://plus.google.com/local/harlev/s/taxi%20%7C%20cab%20%7C%20minicab)

Is it possible to OR keyword in a google places search

Comment: I think this might be a better fit for the Web Applications stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Places API does not current support multiple keywords or names in requests. A Places API - Feature Request for this has been filed [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4278).

If you believe this would be a useful feature please make sure your star the request to let us know you are interested in seeing it added.